# Creating an app that run everytime I turn the screen on

Tags: android, android-studio, screen-lock

I'm using android studio and I was wondering if there's a way to make an app that run every time I turn on the screen (e.g. screen lock). I know this has been asked before, but I can't understand where to put the code for this.. 
please help

Comment: Note to all devs considering this: users will be very upset with you if you do this without *very* good and very clear reasons. Your app will effectively be running *all the time*, consuming precious RAM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
<!-- SCREEN_ON BroadCast intent-filter -->  
< receiver android: name = ".broadcast.LockScreenReceiver" >
  < intent - filter >
  < action android: name = "android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" / >
  < action android: name = "android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" / >
  < action android: name = "android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" / >
  < /intent-filter>  
</receiver >


  //receive broadcast and do something
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT.equals(intent.getAction())) {
      Log.e("scrennOn", "I'm comming!");
    }
  }
```

Comment: The SCREEN_ON/SCREEN_OFF broadcasts [cannot be received through an intent filter declared in your manifest](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_ON). In other words, your app process needs to be already running for this to work, and you have to register for the broadcasts dynamically. Not sure about USER_PRESENT. That one [might work](http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/keyguard/KeyguardViewMediator.java#USER_PRESENT_INTENT), actually.